# Visual Studio Code Blue Block

Tags: visual-studio-code

So this started happening all of a sudden? I can't seem to figure out how I might've enabled this nor how to disable it? I've tried ctrl+esc and all that with 0 results. I've also looked into the settings for highlights, code blocks and indents with no luck. Anyone out there know how to remove this setting from VS Code?

Thanks!

[image: VS CODE Blue Block Code]

Comment: You probably installed an extension for SQL and it highlights the query at the cursor.

Answer (score 10):

Put this line in your settings.json file:

```
“sqltools.highlightQuery”: false
```

Save the file and go back to your SQL file. The highlighting should now be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same setting or configuration happen to me out of no where after doing some visual studio code updates.  I also found that this blue block highlighting only seem to occur on SQL like syntax.  So I looked through my extensions and I only had 2 related to SQL syntax.  I disabled the "SQLTools" extension I had installed and the blue blocks went away:

[image: SQLTools extension]

This extensions official site can be found here:

https://vscode-sqltools.mteixeira.dev/

I haven't looked but may there is a way to disable this setting.